# Azure file copy task Devops Pipelines is failing with error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a build pipeline that includes an Azure File Copy task which copies some files from our build output to an Azure VM.

Every day now for at least a week this task has been failing with the following error:

> ##[error]Failed to enable copy prerequisites. Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension
>   'WinRMCustomScriptExtension' with handler
>   'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified
>   in input.

We have had this issue before a few times, however, the problem has, up until now seamed to corrected itself without any changes by us. This time however, it does not look like the problem is going to resolve itself without some changes or intevention.

Can you help?

Comment: Did you tried below solution? Any good new?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT yes I have tried your solution below, however, the script does not work for me, I am trying everything I can think of, but the script fails with the error: 2019-10-31T12:00:54.9339638Z ##[error]The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMName>/extensions/WinRMCustomScriptExtension' under resource group '<RGName>' was not found. ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound ErrorMessage: The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMName>/extensions/WinRMCustomScriptExtension' under resource group '<RGName>' was not found. StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not Found.

Comment: Did you tried this command `Get-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -VMName "VirtualMachine" -Name "WinRMCustomScriptExtension"`

Comment: You can also run this command to get all the extensions, and check if WinRMCustomScriptExtension really exists or not.`Get-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" -VMName "VirtualMachine" ` OR this command `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMName "myVM" | select Extensions`

Comment: Any update for this case?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT no, I have contact with someone in Microsoft, as soon as I get something I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide some more information?

1. Which version of Copy Files are you using?
2. Are you using Classic or Azure Pipelines?
3. Which agent pool are you using?
4. Can you post the yaml of the Task here like this:

```
    steps:
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Copy Files to: 123'
          inputs:
            TargetFolder: /output
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure File Copy task might fail to remove a custom extension after finishing using it. You can refer to an issue reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4840).

You can try using the newest version of task Azure File Copy. Or try running below scripts to uninstall the extension before using this task as suggested in the issue thread above..

```
$ExtensionName = Get-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -VMName $VM.Name -Name WinRMCustomScriptExtension
Remove-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -VmName $VM.Name -Name $ExtensionName
```